# Use of Digium 24-port FXO analog cards for FreePBX system

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx, freepbx

Does anyone have experience with the installation of `Digium 1AEX2400 Series cards` in a `FreePBX distro` to control `24 POTS lines`? I am researching a new phone system and want to see if anyone has successfully used this hardware before, and if there was any installation trouble that I should know about. It would probably be installed in a `Dell R310 1U rack server`.

For many years we have successfully used `three Zaptel 8-port FXO cards` with `Asterisk 1.4`, and `FreePBX` to set up our company phone system, with `VoIP` phones.

But I can't find any reviews or information on the `24-port Digium cards` that look perfect for this upgrade, using only one `PCI-E slot`, instead of my current 3, requiring an old unsupported `Dell 2U` that takes up rack space.

This question should help all those ITs setting up their own `PBX phone server` to handle 24 POTS (Plain Old Telephone Service) lines to send and receive calls, for more stable audio quality than the now common VoIP trunks you see being used in `FreePBX/Asterisk setups`).

Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Any digium card have be supported by modern dahdi/zaptel drivers

So you can use it in freepbx. If it not see card, likly you need configure it or update drivers.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I'm hoping to hear from anyone who has used the card, that can give their experience with it.

Comment: digium cards are DESIGNED to work with asterisk. sure they work with asterisk. actualy asterisk developed for that cards sale :)